# Open XML document in Excel without TableFormat

Tags: c#, xml, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to open an XML document in Excel with the following code:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)app.Workbooks.OpenXML(@"c:\test.xml", Type.Missing, Excel.XlXmlLoadOption.XlXmlLoadImportToList);
```

The document opens fine but immediately a table format is applied. I would just like to load the date in a plain Excel sheet without any colors or any other formatting.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're doing, but did you try .Open instead of .OpenXML?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to read excel, specify a range of cells to be read, create an xml document and its corresponding nodes, and pick the data from excel to store it into the xml document. is that what you want?